# How to tokenize and use env variables used by docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose

How to tokenize and use env variables used by docker-compose

.env file

```
PROTOCOL=http
# PROTOCOL=https
HOST=www.goo.com
PORT=5424

ROOT_URL=$PROTOCOL://$HOST:$PORT
```

The above doesn't work, what would be the best way to achieve this

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#variable-substitution

Comment: My question was more towards if tokenization is possible in the .env file